# Host java-based telegram bot on server

Tags: java, server, telegram, telegram-bot

I've made a bot using java, and it works perfectly using my laptop as the host machine (the program runs in my machine and telegram users can use my bot as long as i'm running it on my machine).

In order to make the bot online 24/7, I need to host it in some kind of web server.
My bot is simple, it doesn't require databases, it just reacts to some predefined messages, so very little computational power is needed.

So my questions are:

·How can I host my program on a server and how can I make it run continuously?

·Is there a way to make this for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cloud, Like Google Cloud or Microsoft Azure, So grab your bot file and host it on a site that provides 24/7 cloud.
While this is a duplicate of [How can I successfully host my Telegram bot written in Python on the cloud (for free)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161316/how-can-i-successfully-host-my-telegram-bot-written-in-python-on-the-cloud-for)

You should really delete your post and take a look at it.

If that doesn't help, Just find a 24/7 Turned on laptop, Or find a free cloud online or any off-topic hosting site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are many ways to run your bot 24/7. You can go for a RDP, where your bot can run 24/7. You can deploy your telegram bot to cloud like Google Cloud.

For a free way, I will recommend [Heroku](https://herokuapp.com)